# Alternativas ao Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Recentemente soube que para aplicativos que rastreiam usuários (ex: aplicativos de táxi), o Google maps cobra uma licença anual para uso da sua API.

Gostaria de saber se existe outras alternativas de API de mapas para o Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Open Street Map é a alternativa mais famosa e free. Se você googlar `open street map android` vai cair no Wiki deles, e lá vai encontrar mais links para bibliotecas que pode utilizar.

Answer (score 3):

Para usar o *OpenStreetMap* você pode baixar o https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid, vá até a página e baixe o ultimo "release" https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/releases (por exemplo https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/releases/download/osmdroid-parent-5.5/osmdroid-5.5.zip)

Se for *grandle*, adicione a dependência assim:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(COLOQUE A VERSÃO AQUI):release@aar'
}
```

Se for o Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.osmdroid</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmdroid-android</artifactId>
  <version>{COLOQUE A VERSÃO AQUI}</version>
  <classifier>release</classifier>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

No `manifest.xml` adicione (Android6+ ainda requer `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` e `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`/`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` para usar o *osmdroid*):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Um exemplo de layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Mais exemplos de uso:

- https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How%20to%20use%20the%20osmdroid%20library

Outros projetos que usam o *osmdroid*:

- https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Related-Projects